# GIT how can I repair the history of a moved file (specifically for blame, etc)

Tags: git, move, repair

I moved a .js file from one folder to another manually. Now, although GIT seems to have the complete history log for the file, it still seems to treat the move as a delete/create event. 
Further, using git BLAME, I cannot go back to track changes beyond the point that I moved the file.

It's been a month or so and many commits since, but I would love to be able to "repair" that history so that GIT treats the entire commit history as the same file, without the cutoff point at the move.. and I would be able to step back using blame to track changes.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Have you tried the `-M` and `-C` flags to `git blame`?

Answer (score 5):

You should use the git-blame `-C` flag.  This instructs Git to try to figure out where the individual lines actually *came from*, not just when they were committed.  Although this sounds like the same thing, it's different in cases such as yours.

It seems like magic when you use it!  Read [the manual page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) for more info.

Comment: Note to self and others: This is a CAPITAL `C`